# MathJax in Tag Wiki

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, design, mathjax

While editing a little bit in the tag wiki lately, I noticed that the preview for MathJax is somewhat…strange.

Examples include:

- it takes much longer for the preview to update in the tag wiki edit than in answer/question edits
- `$\{$` is not shown in the tag wiki preview
- it chokes when there appears to be markdown in a formula, such as in `$A_{ij} B_{kl}$`; the `_` are interpreted as meant to emphasise `{ij} B`

Is there a particular reason the tag wiki behaves differently from the rest of PSE?

I am using Opera 12.11 build 1661 on Debian Wheezy (amd64).

Comment: Does it affect only the preview or rendering on the usual view as well?

Comment: So far, only the preview: the time it takes to update is not really relevant and the other two problems didn’t show up in the actual rendering (with the "thanks for your suggestion, it will be peer-reviewed…" text box at the top).

Comment: I have the exact same problems in Chrome.

Comment: Is there any specific example I can look at?

Comment: I can reproduce the first two points but not the third. Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m over Windows 7.